# AngleSharp проблема с пасингом картинок

Tags: c#, парсер, anglesharp

Мне нужно спасить данные из сайта [сайт](https://habr.com/ru/all/),мне нужно получить картинку,описание,заголовок статьи.

Заголовок статьи,все работает

```
IEnumerable<IElement> items = document.QuerySelectorAll("a").Where(item => item.ClassName != null && item.ClassName.Contains("post__title_link"));
```

Полученые картинки  проблема:

```
var menuPics = document.QuerySelectorAll("img").Where(el => el.ClassName == null).Select(el => el.GetAttribute("src")).ToList();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть  кроме картинок которые нужны,получаю  не пойми что.
Парсер я использовал из [Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz4ZCr6pnXA),только переделал его под wpf + mvvm.

Comment: Ну а зачем вы берете все изображения со страницы? Берите только [в блоке поста](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMmri.png). То есть я бы на вашем месте нашел этот блок, потом из него уже брал бы картинку, текст, заголовок, а не со всего HTML. Правда я не подскажу как это делается на `AngleSharp`. Кстати, ваш вопрос совершенно не связан с WPF, а значит можно его чуть перефразировать, убрать лишнее, добавить нужные теги и сделать акцент именно на `AngleSharp`, так вы увеличите шанс получить ответ, а то сейчас у вас будто вопрос про WPF и MVVM идет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Мне нужно  взять не все   изображения со страницы,а только те которые в статьи,только не знаю как правильно это сделать!( я только начал изучать  AngleSharp.

Comment: А я вам разве сказал брать все? Прочитайте внимательно то, что написал первым комментарием.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Извените  вас не правильно понял,в чем проблема в тега катинки нету класса,как в титулки  статьи.  `<a href="https://habr.com/ru/post/515538/" class="post__title_link">Новое законодательство РФ о цифровых финансовых активах и цифровой валюте</a>`

Comment: Ну а зачем вам класс у тега? Вот у вас [блок одной новости](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWAIU.png), вы сначала берете сам этот блок (цифра 1), это `article` с классом `post`. Далее **в нем**, а не по всему объекту вы ищете блок с заголовком (цифра 3), это `h2` с классом `post__title`. Дальше, опять же в объекте новости вы ищите кусок, где сам текст (цифра 4), это `div` с классом `post__body` и вот уже в этом блоке с текстом новости вы берете картинку, она там если есть, то всегда одна. То есть у вас иерархия поисков должна быть, а не так, что вы сейчас ищете во всем HTML.

Comment: Вон я вам набросал [простенький пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uud1gk). Первый раз взял в руки этот инструмент, так что может где не так написал, но суть думаю вы поймете. Заметьте, что я не обращаюсь к главному документу, я из него лишь раз получил нужные новости и забыл про него, дальше углубляюсь в данные.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  спасибо,очень благодарен вам!) Вы пролили свет на эту проблему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо большое за помощь EvgeniyZ.

```
using System;
using AngleSharp;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
                    
public class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
        var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
        var document = await context.OpenAsync("https://habr.com/ru/all/");

        var news = document.QuerySelectorAll("article.post");
        foreach (var item in news)
        {
            var content = item.QuerySelector("div.post__text");

            var content_title = item.QuerySelector("h2.post__title").TextContent.Trim();
            var content_image = content.QuerySelector("img")?.GetAttribute("src");
            var content_text = content.TextContent.Trim();

            Console.WriteLine($"Изображение: {content_image}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Заголовок: {content_title}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Текст: {content_text}");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------\n");
        }
    }
}
```